# docker - how to keep the data after docker down and up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i run this command to pull images, up services

```
docker-compose -f dc-all.yml up
```

but i noticed the data keep in the images e.g. database data is gone once i down and up the docker
the command i tried to down the docker.

```
docker-compose -f dc-all.yml down
```

what is the best practice to keep the data?

or how to keep docker running without restart? e.g. windows restart does not

sample yml file

```html
networks:
  test:
services:
  db:
    networks: 
      - pm
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    container_name: mssql
    hostname: mssql
    volumes:
      - ./.db:/var/opt/mssql/
      - /var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./sqlinit.sql:/scripts/sqlinit.sql
    ports:
      - 8010:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Test123!
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
        # Launch MSSQL and send to background
        /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
        # Wait for it to be available
        echo "Waiting for MS SQL to be available"
        /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -l 30 -S mssql -h-1 -V1 -U sa -P Test123! -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT \"YAY WE ARE UP\" , @@servername"
        is_up=$$?
        while [ $$is_up -ne 0 ] ; do 
          echo -e $$(date) 
          /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -l 30 -S mssql -h-1 -V1 -U sa -P Test123! -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT \"YAY WE ARE UP\" , @@servername"
          is_up=$$?
          sleep 5 
        done
        # Run every script in /scripts
        # TODO set a flag so that this is only done once on creation, 
        #      and not every time the container runs
        #for foo in /scripts/*.sql
        /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S mssql -U sa -P Test123! -l 30 -e -i /scripts/sqlinit.sql
        #done
        # So that the container doesn't shut down, sleep this thread
        sleep infinity
      
  zookeeper:
    networks: 
      - pm
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: 1
  
  kafka:
    networks: 
      - pm
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka

  schema-registry:
    networks: 
      - pm
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.2.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: 'schema-registry'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'

  rest-proxy:
    networks: 
      - pm
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.2.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: 'rest-proxy'
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:9092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://rest-proxy:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181' 

 
  katalon:
    networks: 
      - pm
    image: katalonstudio/katalon:latest
    container_name: katalon
    hostname: katalon
    depends_on:
      - db
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
      - rest-proxy
    volumes:
      - ../katalon-service:/katalon/katalon/source
    entrypoint: katalon-execute.sh
    command:
      - -browserType=Web Service
      - -retry=0
      - -statusDelay=15
      - -testSuitePath=Test Suites/TS_IntegrationTestSuites_SQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use volumes like you do in Docker. See the [full doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes) for all the details.

but basically you want:

```
services:
  some_service:    
    volumes:
        - $PWD/data:/path/to/data
```

Comment: the yml file has volumes:
      - ./.db:/var/opt/mssql/
      - /var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./sqlinit.sql:/scripts/sqlinit.sql

Answer (score 1):

You can either mount the docker host directory as below in compose -

```
volumes:
    - /data:/app
```

Using above, all the data generated inside your `/app` directory will show up in `/data` of your docker host.

OR

Use docker logical volumes -

```
volumes:
  - mydata:/data

volumes:
  mydata:
```

Above will create a new volume which can be shared with other services and will not be destroyed once you do a `docker-compose` down. The data on this logical volume stays on your host itself. You can get the directory details using below command -

```
docker inspect mydata
```

Sample output -

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-09-24T05:40:37Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "mydata",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mydata/_data",
        "Name": "mydata",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

`Mountpoint` is where your data exists on the host.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

Comment: i saw my current yml file has volume at db database. but it is like ./ something. i updated main post for the yml file.

Comment: so i can use docker-compose -f dc-all.yml down and docker-compose -f dc-all.yml up to bring them down and up then the data should still maintained in db?

Comment: Yes, since you are already using volumes, data will be maintained.